# Initializing a DatagramSocket in Java

Tags: java, sockets, networking, udp, datagram

I'm going to create a simple server processing some UDP datagrams. My code is as follows:

```
public class UDPServer implements Runnable{

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("UDPServer");
    private DatagramSocket datagramSocket = null;
    private int port;

    public UDPServer(int portNumber) {
        this.port = portNumber;
        try {
            this.datagramSocket = new DatagramSocket(port, InetAddress.getLocalHost());
        } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            logger.info("Server creating failed 1...");
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            logger.info("Server creating failed 2...");
        }
        logger.info("Server created...");
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "Datagram socket: INETAddress: {0} Port: {1}", new Object[]{datagramSocket.getInetAddress(), datagramSocket.getPort()});
    }

    private void runServer() {
        logger.info("Starting the server...");
        try {
            while (true) {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[64];
                DatagramPacket receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Waiting for an incoming packet on {0}", this.datagramSocket.getInetAddress());
                datagramSocket.receive(receivedPacket);
                logger.log(Level.INFO, "Received packet from: {0}", receivedPacket.getSocketAddress());
                new DatagramConsumer(receivedPacket).start();
            }
        } catch (SocketException ex) {
            // logging...
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // logging
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.runServer();
    }
}
```

It simply creates a server, and provides a method for retrieving and processing datagrams...
Something I do not understand is, when I'm creating the server object:

```
UDPServer server = null;
        try {
            server = new UDPServer(12395);
            Thread serverThread = new Thread(server);
            serverThread.start();
            serverThread.join();
        }
```

I see the output like this:

```
INFO: Server created...
INFO: Datagram socket: INETAddress: null Port: -1
INFO: Starting the server...
INFO: Waiting for an incoming packet on null
```

I'm new to networking stuff and I do not know what I'm making wrong... I was expecting that my server should listen for incoming datagrams on definied port and local address...

Answer (score 0):

Use `datagramSocket.getLocalSocketAddress()` for display instead.